# HTML Table: Removing borders around empty cells

Tags: html, html-table

For some reason I'm struggling with this, in HTML I'm practicing with tables by making a calendar. I have a table with headers and some data and everything works okay but I end up with borders around empty cells. I only want cells with data and the table itself to have a border.

Am I approaching this wrong?

Also, is there a way to write data to a specific cell in the table using row and column values?

Here is an edited portion of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> Victor's Fall 2015 Timetable</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th> Monday </th>
            <th> Tuesday </th>
            <th> Wedenesday </th>
            <th> Thursday </th>
            <th> Friday </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th> 11:00 </th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td rowspan="2">Database Lecture</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th> 11:30 </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th> 12:00 </th>
                <td></td>
                <td rowspan="2">Communications Lecture</td>
                <td rowspan="3">Database Lab</td>
                <td></td>
                <td rowspan="2">Java Lecture</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th> 12:30 </th>
        </tr>       

        <tr>
            <th> 1:00 </th>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this page static?? or dynamic generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use for `table` css `border-collapse: separate;empty-cells: hide;`

There is example :

```css
table
{
    border-collapse: separate;
    empty-cells: hide;
}
```

```html
 <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th> Monday </th>
            <th> Tuesday </th>
            <th> Wedenesday </th>
            <th> Thursday </th>
            <th> Friday </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th> 11:00 </th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td rowspan="2">Database Lecture</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th> 11:30 </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th> 12:00 </th>
                <td></td>
                <td rowspan="2">Communications Lecture</td>
                <td rowspan="3">Database Lab</td>
                <td></td>
                <td rowspan="2">Java Lecture</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th> 12:30 </th>
        </tr>       

        <tr>
            <th> 1:00 </th>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

**Update** based on OP comment :

It's in `css` file, but, if You not using `css` file (?) then You can put in `table` after `border="1"` ... just add `style="border-collapse: separate; empty-cell:hide;"`

`<table border="1" style="border-collapse: separate; empty-cells: hide;">` ... and so one rest of Your html.

Comment: I've seen this solution before, but I am unsure where to put that piece of code. All I have is one .html file with my code that I'm editing on Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

If your page is Static then you can add `.noborder` class to empty `td` tag

```
.noborder {
border-style: none;
}
```

`<td class='noborder'></td>` won't have border

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fit in with the what you are trying to do, but one option would be to give each an id with the "coordinates"

For example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="r0c0"> Row 0, Col 0</td>
        <td id="r0c1"> Row 0, Col 1</td>
        <td id="r0c2"> Row 0, Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="r1c0"> Row 1, Col 0</td>
        <td id="r1c1"> Row 1, Col 1</td>
        <td id="r1c2"> Row 1, Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="r2c0"> Row 2, Col 0</td>
        <td id="r2c1"> Row 2, Col 1</td>
        <td id="r2c2"> Row 2, Col 2</td>
    </tr>
```

With more information, I might be able to give you a different/better solution, if this wouldn't work.

UPDATE: I reread the question and realized this only answers part of your question. Hope it helps anyway!!